# Vue js text add animation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I click on a component, the text changes. Is it possible to smoothly animate this addition of text and increase the height of the block?

[image]

[image]

Some example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello, i need smooth animation when text added(click me please)'
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello, i need smooth animation when text added(click me please)'
  },
  methods: {
   addText() {
    console.log('1');
     TweenLite.to(document.getElementById('test'), 2, {text:"This is animation with GSAP (vue plugin to animate anything) and i don't know how to animate it smooth", ease:Linear.easeNone});
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app, #app2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" @click="message = message+message+message">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<div id="app2" @click="addText">
  <p id="test">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  In fact Vue provides a very robust engine for performing pretty much any kind of web GUI animation you could imagine, using a concept called "transitions".  All you need to know is basic CSS!  Here's the main documentation for it, and there are plenty of other examples to be found on Google.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I tried to find in Google variants of the decision, but specifically that is necessary to me-didn't find. when the text field is changed in state > this increases the height of div, and still i don't find any solutions how to make this increase smooth

Answer (score -1):

U can watch the text value. like this [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html).

Comment: tried this option. when you use it, the text is added gradually, but it goes as if printed by a person and when you move to a new line still twitches

Comment: I guess the problem is your animation, can you give an example on codepen ?

Comment: I understand your problem. This is hard to implement, because transition not work for ```height: auto```.   You have to use JS to get the height and set a clearly value.